# Spring Junit4TestRunner Autowired null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

```
public interface Animal {
    public String getName();
    public int getAge();
}
```

---

```
@Component
public class Dog implements Animal{

    @Override public String getName() {
        return "Puppy";
    }

    @Override public int getAge() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Component("cdiExample")
public class CDIExample {
    @Autowired
    private Dog dog;

    public void display() {
        try {
            System.out.println("com.example.Animal ---> " + dog.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:beans.xml");
            Animal animal=context.getBean("dog", Animal.class);
            System.out.println(animal.getName());
        }
    }
```

### Application Context

```
 <context:annotation-config/>
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.example"/>
```

### Junit Test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:test-beans.xml" })
public class CDIExampleTest {

    //@Autowired
    private CDIExample cdiExample;

    @Before
    public void before() throws Exception {
        cdiExample = new CDIExample();
    }

    @Test
    public void testDisplay() throws Exception {
        cdiExample.display();

    }

}
```

### Test-context

```
<import resource="classpath*:/beans.xml" />
```

If i run the above Junittestcase, autowire is null.

If i execute the main method and Using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext, bean is loading and autowire is not null.

Comment: It cannot be null as spring will throw an exception if it cannot be auto wired. So you must be having something wrong in how you run your testcase.

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to be cdiExample in you test case not being a spring bean. You are manually instantiating it in @Before.

Instead try this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:test-beans.xml" })
public class CDIExampleTest {

    @Autowired
    private CDIExample cdiExample;

    @Test
    public void testDisplay() throws Exception {
        cdiExample.display();

    }

}
```

This way the cdiExample will be injected from the spring context which will have dog autowired by spring.